# Flutter : Switching from one tab to another from Tab bar causing building of tabs in between

Tags: flutter

I have a page with 10 tabs and I notice that when I jump from Tab 1 to Tab 10, some of the tabs in between are built and disposed off.
I do not want this behaviour as each tab makes heavy network calls.
How can I avoid this behaviour?

Comment: There is a github issue opened for a similar problem : https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/14316

Comment: Hi, have you solved this issue?